# Different command behavior if argument is not a single token

Tags: macros, expansion

In defining a new LaTeX command, I'm looking for a way to distinguish whether its argument is a single token or not. In other words, I would like `\foo x` to be equivalent to `\something{x}`, and `\foo{xy}` to `\somethingelse{xy}` (as opposed to `\something{xy}`).
Would that be possible somehow, possibly without using evil hacks?

I tried looking at the documentation for `xparse` and `etoolbox`, but I could not find anything useful. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`expl3` has a conditional just for that: `\tl_if_single_token:nTF`.  It will return true only if the argument is exactly a single token.  It returns false if the argument is empty, or if the argument is a braced group containing any number of tokens.  `expl3` also has `\tl_if_single:nTF` that returns true on `x` as well as on `{x}`, whereas `\tl_if_single_token:nTF` returns false on the latter.

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfSingleTokenTF \tl_if_single_token:nTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfSingleItemTF \tl_if_single:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \texttt{>#1: }%
  \IfSingleTokenTF{#1}%
    {\something}%
    {\somethingelse}{#1}}

\newcommand\something[1]{(single:#1)}
\newcommand\somethingelse[1]{(multiple:#1)}

\begin{document}
\foo{}

\foo{ }

\foo{x}

\foo{ x}

\foo{xy}

\foo{{xy}}
\end{document}
```

---

As Frank noted in the comment, the code above works fine for XeTeX and LuaTeX because those engines tread UTF-8 characters like `ä` or  as a single token.  pdfTeX, on the other hand, treats `ä` as two and  as four tokens, which when typesetting combine to produce a single glyph, thus the test above results as multiple tokens.

Depending on your use case (or if you want cross-engine compatibility) you might want to treat UTF-8 characters as a single token, in which case a bit more code is needed to check for those cases in pdfTeX:

> [image]

The code first does the `\tl_if_single_token:nTF` test to eliminate the obvious case that the argument is indeed a single token.  If that returns false, then we look at meaning of the first token in the argument, and if it is `\UTFviii@(two|three|four)@octets` then we know the first token is an UTF-8 char, in which case we remove the remaining tokens that compose the char and then test if what remains is empty: if it is, the only thing in the argument was the UTF-8 char, so return true, otherwise return false.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF
    { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
    { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
  {
    \cs_new_eq:NN \IfSingleTokenTF \tl_if_single_token:nTF
    \use_none:n
  }
  { \makeatletter \use:n }
  {
    \makeatother
    \scan_new:N \s__fudo
    \prg_new_conditional:Npnn \fudo_if_single_token:n #1 { T, F, TF }
      {
        \tl_if_single_token:nTF {#1}
          { \prg_return_true: }
          {
            \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
              {
                \use:e
                  {
                    \exp_not:N \__fudo_if_single_token_aux:w
                      \exp_not:o { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }
                      \tl_to_str:n { UTFviii@ one @octets } ~ \s__fudo
                      \exp_not:n {#1} \s__fudo
                  }
              }
              { \prg_return_false: }
          }
      }
    \use:e
      {
        \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__fudo_if_single_token_aux:w
          #1 \tl_to_str:n { UTFviii@ } #2 \tl_to_str:n { @octets } ~
          #3 \s__fudo #4 \s__fudo
      }
      {
        \str_case:nnTF {#2}
          {
            { one   } { \exp_after:wN \__fudo_single_chk:w \use_none:n }
            { two   } { \exp_after:wN \__fudo_single_chk:w \use_none:nn }
            { three } { \exp_after:wN \__fudo_single_chk:w \use_none:nnn }
            { four  } { \exp_after:wN \__fudo_single_chk:w \use_none:nnnn }
          }
          { #4 \s__fudo }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
    \cs_new:Npn \__fudo_single_chk:w #1 \s__fudo
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
    \cs_new_eq:NN \IfSingleTokenTF \fudo_if_single_token:nTF
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \texttt{>#1: }%
  \IfSingleTokenTF{#1}%
    {\something}%
    {\somethingelse}{#1}}

\newcommand\something[1]{(single:#1)}
\newcommand\somethingelse[1]{(multiple:#1)}

\begin{document}
\foo{}

\foo{ }

\foo{x}

\foo{ä}

% \foo{鸟}

% \foo{}

\foo{ x}

\foo{xy}

\foo{{xy}}
\end{document}
```

The code does not understand `é` (`U+0065 Latin Small Letter E` + `U+0301 Combining Acute Accent`) as a single character. You have to input the *proper* Unicode `U+00E9 Latin Small Letter E with Acute`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Too bad the Overleaf pre-parser does not like LaTeX3-style syntax (underscores etc.), but it works anyway :)

Comment: @fudo You can add `%%begin novalidate` before the `expl3` code, and `%%end novalidate` after it so that Overleaf won't check that bit of code

Comment: Great, thanks again!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik small problem Phelype:  \foo{ä} is single in XeTeX/LuaTeX but multiple in pdfTeX. While correct, perhaps not what is wanted, a user facing 2e command should probably detect multi-byte chars (and LICRs?)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Hah, good catch! I added a version that understands utf-8

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Something for the `text` module? As it's really about document-level input?

Comment: @fudo Depending on your use-case, you might want to take a look at the new version I added

Comment: @JosephWright Yeah, maybe it would be useful.  Something like `\tl` function but `\text`: `\text_if_single_char:nTF`, and `\text_if_head_is_N_type:nTF` and so on (`\text_reverse:n` will be fun :)

Comment: how many characters is é ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed the answer ;-)

Comment: +1 (can't really give it as I had already upvoted the answer) for accuracy, but this is not really needed in my case since my command is used in equations (where utf8 is unlikely). In fact, what turned out to be most useful to me is the "single item" version, not the single token one. Sorry if my question was not clear about that.

Comment: @fudo Don't worry ;-)  I imagined you would need the single item version: checking for a single _token_ is a really specialised, most likely useful only for programming tasks (and even then, rarely)

Answer (score 7):

EDITED to make it expandable! (see **SUPPLEMENT**)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\fooaux#1\endfoo}
\def\fooaux#1#2\endfoo{\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  \expandafter\fooproper\else\expandafter\fooalt\fi{#1#2}}
\newcommand\fooproper[1]{FOO! #1}
\newcommand\fooalt[1]{bar #1}
\begin{document}
\foo a

\foo{A}

\edef\z{\foo{ab}}% EXPANDABLE

\z
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

Ulrich rightly points out that the above simple solution has several potential chinks, depending on what the OP expects to get thrown at the `\foo` macro.  In particular, if the argument is a delimited space, or contains a leading space as part of a delimited argument, the space will not be detected.  Further, if the argument contains the macro `\endfoo`, likewise that will spoof the result.

At the expense of expandability, I address Ulrich's concerns about spaces by calling on the facilities of `tokcycle`, which has no problem discerning spaces in its input stream.  Thus, I show various examples and how much can be discerned about their content on the fly.

The only restriction is that the argument stream not contain the token `endtokcycraw`, which is reserved by the `tokcycle` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\foo{\def\leadingspace{F}\futurelet\foofirst\fooA}
\newcommand\fooA{\ifx\foofirst\bgroup\expandafter\foodelim\else
  \expandafter\fooundelim\fi}
\newcounter{tokcnt}
\newcommand\foodelim[1]{%
  \setcounter{tokcnt}{0}%
  \tokcycle
  {\stepcounter{tokcnt}}%
  {\addtocounter{tokcnt}{2}\processtoks{##1}}%
  {\stepcounter{tokcnt}}%
  {\ifnum\value{tokcnt}=0\relax\def\leadingspace{T}\fi\stepcounter{tokcnt}}%
  {#1}%
  \tctestifnum{\value{tokcnt}=0}{\foonil}{%
  \tctestifnum{\value{tokcnt}=1}{\fooone}{\foomulti}}{#1}}
\newcommand\fooundelim[1]{Undelimited argument to foo: #1}
\newcommand\foonil[1]{Delimited null argument to foo}
\newcommand\fooone[1]{Delimited single token to foo: #1%
  \if T\leadingspace (Space)\fi}
\newcommand\foomulti[1]{Delimited multi-token to foo: #1%
 \if T\leadingspace\ (Leading Space)\fi}
\begin{document}
\foo a \par
\foo{} \par
\foo{ } \par
\foo{A} \par
\foo{ B} \par
\foo{C D} \par
\foo{ab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can save `\expandafter`s by rewriting `\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` as `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Good point.

Comment: If I get this right, it strictly spoken is not a test for a single _token_ but is a test for a single _undelimited argument_. It is relied on `\foo`'s argument  not being empty/blank and not containing the token `\endfoo` unless as 1st token. If `\foo`'s argument has leading space-tokens these will be discarded instead of being considered when `\fooaux`'s 1st undelimited argument is gathered.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Those are all good points, though I think the `\endfoo` point is more of a quibble, as one chooses a delimiter that 100 monkeys typing at typewriters would require a million years to stumble across (though maybe `\endfoo` is not quite that).  The discarded space issue is more significant and I will think about addressing it.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Please see my supplement

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes "Those are all good points,..."  I myself think, these are all moot/"academical" points and I have been a nitpicker. ;-)  Actually my main concern is not about every edge case and unlikely case working out. It is about providing to newcomers/beginners, who probably aren't that skilled in reading TeX-code, a precise description of what the code provided does in which circumstances. (But I often face the problem of needing to use TeX-related terminology/jargon which a newcomer/beginner probably is not yet familiar to...  ;-)  )

Comment: @UlrichDiez I understand and agree.  Precision of terminology is good; yet as you note, it can be overwhelming to the newcomer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes "Precision of terminology is good; yet as you note, it can be overwhelming to the newcomer."  That's a true word, which I unfortunately do not always heed! ;-) Please feel free to remind me of it whenever you see the need of doing so. :-)   From time to time I am sort of carried away when it comes to explaining concepts related to (La)TeX. Then my attempts to work out the context end up getting lost in subtle details, which doesn't really help people to get an overview first.

Answer (score 4):

Preliminary remarks:

1. The special case of the argument being empty/consisting of zero tokens also is one of the cases where the argument is not a single token. (In the example below the corresponding expandable test is `\UD@CheckWhetherNull`.)
2. TeX strips off the outermost level of matching surrounding curly braces from a macro-argument if present: If `\foo` is a macro processing a single undelimited argument, then `\foo x`  and `\foo{x}` yield the same.
3. Explicit space-tokens (explicit character-tokens of catcode 10 and charcode 32) need special treatment when processed via macros: When gathering tokens that form an undelimited argument TeX discards preceding explicit space-tokens. Therefore an explicit space-token can only be processed as undelimited macro-argument if nested in braces. (In the example below the corresponding expandable test is `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace`.)
4. Curly braces (`{` or `}`) also get tokenized as tokens, as explicit character-tokens of catcode 1(begin group) or 2(end group): With `\foo{{x}}` the argument of `\foo` consists of the three tokens  `{1`, `x11` and `}2`. Thus this is a case where the argument is not a single token. (In the example below the corresponding expandable test is `\UD@CheckWhetherBrace`.)

In the example below with the expandable macro `\CheckWhetherSingleToken` the carrying out of the tests mentioned above is triggered via `\romannumeral`-expansion. Therefore in expansion-contexts the result is obtained after two expansion-steps, e.g., after "hitting" `\CheckWhetherSingleToken` via `\expandafter` twice/after "hitting" the first token of `\CheckWhetherSingleToken`'s toplevel-expansion via `\expandafter`.

(The gist of `\romannumeral`-expansion is:

1. TeX expands expandable tokens while gathering the first token of a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity that is to be converted by `\romannumeral`.
2. In case the value of the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity gathered is not positive TeX will silently "eat"/discard the tokens forming the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity without delivering anything in return.

Therefore you can (ab?)use `\romannumeral` for tricking TeX into doing a lot of expansion- and shuffling-around-of-tokens/macro-arguments-work as long as it is ensured that in the end the resulting token-sequence begins with a TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity whose value is not positive.)

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\makeatletter    
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@removespace, \UD@stopromannumeral,  \UD@CheckWhetherNull, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherBrace, \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace, 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@removespace{\UD@Exchange{ }{\def\UD@removespace}{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\CheckWhetherSingleToken[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@secondoftwo}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{\UD@secondoftwo}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#1}{%
         \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}%
      }{%
         \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\something[1]{This is something with single-token-argument: (#1)}
\newcommand\somethingelse[1]{This is something else with multi-token-argument or zero-token-argument=empty argument: (#1)}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \CheckWhetherSingleToken{#1}{\something}{\somethingelse}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb|\foo x| yields: \foo x\\
\verb|\foo{x}| yields: \foo{x}\\
\verb|\foo{{x}}| yields: \foo{{x}}\\
\verb|\foo{xy}| yields: \foo{xy}\\
\verb|\foo{{xy}}| yields: \foo{{xy}}\\
\verb|\foo{ }| yields: \foo{ }\\
\verb|\foo{ a}| yields: \foo{ a}\\
\verb|\foo{}| yields: \foo{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\foo{ä}` yields multi-token for pdfTeX (which is true or not, depending on what you are testing :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The test is not about characters of .tex-input but is about **tokens** that came into being by tokenizing .tex-input. Of course the result depends both on the TeX-engine in use and on the encoding of the .tex-input-file in use. With .tex-input-files in utf-8-encoding/multibyte-encoding each character is formed by multiple bytes whereof each byte is taken for a(n active character-)token with traditional 8-bit TeX-engines like pdfLaTeX (if the inputenc-package with utf8-encoding is loaded, which is standard/the default nowadays).