# Expandable macro that extracts the first character of UTF-8/cyrillic string without additional packages

Tags: unicode, characters, strings, cyrillic

I would like to have an expandable macro that extracts the first (and sometimes the second) character of UTF-8/Cyrillic text strings without using additional packages. No simple solutions from TeX or LaTeX work with UTF-8/Cyrillic strings.

I give below an example of a working macro, which is partially taken from [Get the first and second character of a macro argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549200/get-the-first-and-second-character-of-a-macro-argument/549203) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstof}[1]{\@car#1\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this example fails with the error `Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (Ð\par)` using Cyrillic strings like `\firstof{Владимир}`.

I roughly understand that by default TeX is not adapted to manipulating strings with multibyte characters, but this problem is solved in some packages. However, I do not want to use other packages for such a simple problem (as it seems at first glance) and I will be grateful to the community for help and tips.

Ideally, I would like to have an expandable macro like `\newcommand{\firstof}[2][1]{.....}`, which by default for UTF-8/Cyrillic strings returns the value of the first character, for example, in the case of `\firstof{Владимир}` returns `В`, and for `\firstof[2]{Владимир}` returns `Вл`, and these chars could be used in `/ifx` to compare with others and written to a file using `\write`.

Comment: Why "without additional package"? Remember that package is just other people's code, so you can just copy their code and include in yours (if the license permit).

Comment: • Just use `char_to_utfviii_bytes:n` from expl3. You can learn expl3, right? • "simple problem" remember that TeX's built in functionality is **very** limited. and without expl3 you need to do massive data juggling to get useful computation.  • It looks like you're not using LuaTeX, want to give it a try? Programming in Lua is much simpler.

Comment: Getting the first or second character is doable, but you won't be able to compare `Вл` with an `\ifx` (and get the result you expect) because each of those characters is two tokens (thus four tokens in total) and `\ifx` only compares two tokens at a time.  You could compare with `\pdfstrcmp` though

Comment: @user202729 Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with LaTeX3/expl3 syntax, but I could probably learn it. As it turned out, the only package for PdfLaTeX that can correctly extract Cyrillic and ASCII characters from strings is `xstring`. But unfortunately its commands are not expandable and this then causes a lot of problems when concatenating author name strings in loops and then writing them to a file.

Comment: @user202729 And also I've only heard about the Lua language, but I'm not familiar with it. My programming knowledge ended many years ago in the Pascal.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, now I understand that working with Unicode is not just a difficult problem, it makes my hair stand up from "the simple problem" :) (as I thought at first)

Comment: Up to you. If you want to be able to do more than trivial work in TeX (without asking other people for help, that is) you need to learn some programming language. Expl3, Lua, or even plain TeX. (Python works too with pythontex, but requires shell-escape or invoking external command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each byte of the UTF-8 encoding is a separate token in pdflatex, however you can recognise the leading token which tells you how many bytes are needed. This version covers the one and two byte cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstof}[1]{\expandafter\checkfirst#1\@nil}
\def\checkfirst#1{%
  \ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%
  \expandafter\gettwooctets
  \else
  \expandafter\@car\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}
\def\gettwooctets#1#2#3\@nil{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to handle the rest of the input as opposed to discarding everything after the first letter, you can make a small change so that you pass in a command to appy to the remaning text. If you pass in `\gobble`  it extracts as before. If you pass in `\firstofx\gobble` then it exctracts the first letter of the remaining text so you get two letters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstofx}[2]{\expandafter\checkfirst#2\@nil{#1}}
\def\checkfirst#1{%
  \ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%
  \expandafter\gettwooctetsx
  \else
  \expandafter\getasciix\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}

\def\getasciix#1#2\@nil#3{#1#3{#2}}

\def\gettwooctetsx#1#2#3\@nil#4{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2#4{#3}}

\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\firstofx\gobble{Vladimir}

\firstofx{\firstofx\gobble}{Vladimir}

\firstofx\gobble{Владимир}

\firstofx{\firstofx\gobble}{Владимир}


\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks, David for the elegant, nice and short solution!

Comment: @Crosfield Except that there might be some indeterminate amount of code hidden behind `\UTFviii@two@octets`... if it's library code it doesn't matter if it's long or short anyway. (okay, maybe not that large, just one or two constants to compare with)

Comment: @user202729 not sure what you mean?  `\UTFviii@two@octets` is a core latex command it has a known definition and so I'm not sure what you mean by indeterminate? (actually its expansion isn't consulted here so it doesn't really matter what its definition is, just that the first byte of two byte characters have a definition that starts this way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's only with regard to the comment above... what I mean is, despite the short code, the logic might be complex (as complex as the other solutions) if the function is implemented internally with lots of code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Did I understand correctly that to get the first and second character I should use `\UTFviii@four@octets` and for this I should use the functions like
`\newcommand{\firstsecondof}[1]{\expandafter\checkfirstsecond#2\@nil}`
`\def\checkfirstsecond#1{%`
`\ifx\UTFviii@four@octets#1\expandafter\getfouroctets`
`\else\expandafter\@car#1\@nil\@car\@cdr#1\@nil\@nil\fi`
`\def\getfouroctets#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{\UTFviii@four@octets#1#2#3#4}`

Comment: no `\UTFviii@four@octets` would be used for 4-byte UTF-8 as used for higher planes of Unicode. To get two characters  you would  need to call this command twice (after modifying it not to discard the rest)

Comment: @user202729 I don't use any complicated hidden macros here just literally a couple of expansions of commands defined in the answer. It does assume knowledge of how UTF-8 is encoded in latex, but all solutions will need that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Excuse me, I didn't quite understand how I can modify the command so as not to discard the rest. I understand that for non-UTF-8 strings, I need to concatenate a) `\@car` for `#1` and b) `\@car` from `\@cdr` for `#1`, but I absolutely do not understand how to modify the case with `\gettwooctets` for two chars. Like `\def\getfouroctets#1#2#3#4#5\@nil{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2\UTFviii@two@octets#3#4}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Excuse me again, I'll ask for help again. Strangely, I got the second character for Cyrillic strings (as I described in the comment above), but I can't get the first and second characters at the same time for ASCII strings. If you imagine that your function should be adapted to extract two characters at once, then the second case for `\ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%` looks like this now `\expandafter\@car#1\@car\@cdr#1%`. But it only outputs the first character. The second character is empty. How can I extract the first and second characters at the same time?

Comment: @Crosfield I added a working version to my answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your great help! I probably need to try to finish reading The TeXbook to understand the logic of the solution

Answer (score 3):

This should probably work.  I defined `\headof` and `\tailof` (using code stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545784/134574) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596517/134574)), which do what their names promise.  If you use `\headof*` (or `\tailof*`), it will expand its argument, so you can effortlessly get the nth character out of a sequence by nesting `\headof*` and `\tailof*` (pretty much like `car` and `cdr` in lisp, if you're into that).  For example, the fourth character of `Владимир` can be extracted with

```latex
\headof*{\tailof*{\tailof*{\tailof{Владимир}}}}
```

Annoyingly easy :)

You can then compare strings using the primitive `\pdfstrcmp` or a higher level `\str_if_eq:eeTF`.  `\ifx` won't work because it compares two tokens, and `л` (for example) is two tokens by itself (assuming you're using pdfTeX, of course).

If the argument is empty, the result is also empty.  If the head is a group of tokens (within `{`...`}`), the group is treated as a single thing and returned without the outer braces.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \headof { s +m }
  { \IfBooleanT {#1} { \exp_args:Ne } \crosfield_text_head:n {#2} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \tailof { s +m }
  { \IfBooleanT {#1} { \exp_args:Ne } \crosfield_text_tail:n {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \crosfield_text_head:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__crosfield_get_head:Nw #1 \q_stop }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
          { \exp_not:o { \use_i_delimit_by_q_stop:nw #1 \q_stop } }
          { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { } { ~ } }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \crosfield_text_tail:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__crosfield_get_tail:Nw #1 \q_stop }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
          { \exp_not:o { \use_none:n #1 } }
          { \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { } { \exp_not:o { \exp:w \exp_end_continue_f:w #1 } } }
      }
  }
\bool_lazy_or:nnTF
    { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
    { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_get_head:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop { \exp_not:N #1 }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_get_tail:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop { \exp_not:n {#2} }
    \use_none:n
  }
  { \makeatletter \use:n }
  {
    \makeatother
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_get_head:Nw
      { \__crosfield_head_tail:NNw \use_i:nn }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_get_tail:Nw
      { \__crosfield_head_tail:NNw \use_ii:nn }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_head_tail:NNw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
      {
        \use:e
          {
            \exp_not:N \__crosfield_head_tail:w
              \exp_not:o { \token_to_meaning:N #2 }
              \tl_to_str:n { UTFviii@ one @octets } ~
          }   \q_stop { #2 #3 } #1
      }
    \use:e
      {
        \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__crosfield_head_tail:w
          #1 \tl_to_str:n { UTFviii@ } #2 \tl_to_str:n { @octets } ~ #3
          \exp_not:N \q_stop #4 #5
      }
      {
        \str_case:nnTF {#2}
          {
            { one   } { \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNw #5 }
            { two   } { \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNw #5 }
            { three } { \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNNw #5 }
            { four  } { \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNNNw #5 }
          }
          { #4 \q_stop }
          { \ERROR? }
      }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNw #1 #2 #3 \q_stop
      { \exp_not:o { #1 {#2} {#3} } }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNw #1 #2#3 #4 \q_stop
      { \exp_not:o { #1 {#2#3} {#4} } }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNNw #1 #2#3#4 #5 \q_stop
      { \exp_not:o { #1 {#2#3#4} {#5} } }
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_head_or_tail:NNNNNw #1 #2#3#4#5 #6 \q_stop
      { \exp_not:o { #1 {#2#3#4#5} {#6} } }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \StrCompare \str_if_eq:eeTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\StrCompare
  {\headof*{\tailof{Владимир}}}{\detokenize{л}}
  {\true}{\false}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Phelype for the reply! I compiled your example. The `\StrCompare` function really works and correctly compares the values, and maybe I misunderstood something, but the `\headof{Владимир}` function does not output anything in PDF (unlike `\headof{Vladimir}`, which outputs `V`).

Comment: @Crosfield You will need a font with Cyrillic glyphs to display Cyrillic: either, for pdflatex, use a legacy T2A encoding font; or use `fontspec` and a unicode/OpenType font like in Mico's answer, for xelatex/lualatex.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks for the advice, but I'm using fonts with cyrillic characters. Commands in the preamble `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` allow Cyrillic fonts to be used. Any Cyrillic text inserted after `\begin{document}` will be output to PDF with this settings and pdflatex engine.

Comment: @Crosfield I don't know what to tell you (besides what Cicada said).  If I take the document in my answer and write `\headof*{\tailof{Владимир}}`, I get `л` in the pdf (also with just `\headof{Владимир}`, but `В` looks an awful lot like an ASCII `B`, so I tested with something else :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It was probably some kind of glitch. I'm using macOS with MacTeX and TeXShop which is a little bit buggy in the latest version. I remember exactly that yesterday your example worked halfway only (I described the problems that were yesterday). Today I opened it - everything is ok! :) Thanks, Phelype! I understand correctly, the asterisk version is used in cases where there are nested `\headof` or `\tailof` commands?

Comment: @Crosfield Yes, the `*` tells the command to expand its argument (`\fullexpandarg` in `xstring` parlance) so nested usage is less painful.  `\headof*{\tailof{ABC}}` evaluates the argument (thus `\tailof`) before evaluating `\headof`, so you get `B`.  `\headof{\tailof{ABC}}` evaluates in order (so `\headof`) and the output is `\tailof` (then an error because it will be missing an argument)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the help. I will try to look at the abilitiy of the LaTeX3

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The solution doesn't employ the standard `string.sub` Lua function, at it isn't unicode-aware. Instead, it employs the `unicode.utf8.sub` function to extract the first `n` (by default, `n=1`) characters of the string argument. The macro `\firstof` is expandable.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} % select a suitable opentype text font

\newcommand\firstof[2][1]{\directlua{%
    tex.sprint ( unicode.utf8.sub ( "#2" , 1 , #1 ) ) }}

\newcommand\zzz{Владимир} 

\begin{document}
\firstof{\zzz}, \firstof[2]{\zzz}, \firstof[4]{\zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In analogy to `\firstof`, one could define `\lastof` like this: `\newcommand\lastof[2][1]{\directlua{ tex.sprint ( unicode.utf8.sub ( "#2" , -#1 ) ) }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to look at the abilitiy of the Lua language