# Expandable macro that extracts the first characters of many words for UTF-8/cyrillic or UTF-8/ASCII string without additional packages

Tags: unicode, characters, strings, cyrillic

There was a problem to slightly change the macro described in [Expandable macro that extracts the first character of UTF-8/cyrillic string without additional packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631869/expandable-macro-that-extracts-the-first-character-of-utf-8-cyrillic-string-with) for the argument which may contain two or more words. That is, for example, for the argument Vladimir Fedorovich it would return V.F., and for Владимир Фёдорович - В.Ф.
Here is a working example by the highly respected **David Carlisle** for a one-word argument (of course it can contain many words, but only the first letter of the first word will be extracted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstof}[1]{\expandafter\checkfirst#1\@nil}
\def\checkfirst#1{%
  \ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%
  \expandafter\gettwooctets
  \else
  \expandafter\@car\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}
\def\gettwooctets#1#2#3\@nil{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

\end{document}
```

I need the `\firstof{Vladimir Fedorovich}` macro call to return `V.F.` and the call `\firstof{Владимир Фёдорович}` - `В.Ф.`. But theoretically, there can be more than 2 words in the argument.

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following does what you want.

I coded it in L3 instead of on the low level David used. The basic idea is still the same, if it starts with something that expands to `\UTFviii@two@octets` we collect those two octets, else we just use the first character. However, this also uses `\text_purify:n` on the input to ensure the input to the loop is only text.

Then we simply split at each space (we have to check whether we're done with `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n`) and get our first character (or the two that make up the UTF8 octet pair).

The macro `\firstofwords` takes as its first argument the stuff it should put after each first letter of each word, and the second argument is the list of words separated by spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstof}[1]{\expandafter\checkfirst#1\@nil}
\def\checkfirst#1{%
  \ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%
  \expandafter\gettwooctets
  \else
  \expandafter\@car\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}
\def\gettwooctets#1#2#3\@nil{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \crosfield_first_of_words:nn #1#2
  { \exp_not:e { \__crosfield_first_of_words:e { \text_purify:n {#2} } {#1} } }
\group_begin:
\cs_set:Npn \__crosfield_tmp:n #1
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words:n ##1 ##2
      {
        \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:nw {##2} ##1 #1 % #1 is a space
          \q_recursion_tail #1 % #1 is a space
          \q_recursion_stop
      }
  }
\__crosfield_tmp:n { ~ }
\group_end:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__crosfield_first_of_words:n { e }
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:nw #1 #2 ~
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
    \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:oNTF {#2} \UTFviii@two@octets
      { \__crosfield_first_of_words_aux:nnw #2 \q_stop }
      { \tl_head:n {#2} }
    \exp_not:n {#1}
    \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:nw {#1}
  }
\makeatother
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF { o }
% there can't be a \q_stop in the argument as that would've caused an infinite
% loop in \text_purify:n, so this is fine and faster than allowing arbitrary
% contents.
\cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words_aux:nnw #1#2#3 \q_stop
  { \exp_not:n { #1#2 } }

% define a LaTeX2e name for the above function
\cs_new_eq:NN \firstofwords \crosfield_first_of_words:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

\firstofwords{.\ }{Vladimir Владимир} example

\firstofwords{.}{foo bar baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** If you only need the second argument and want to put a `.` inbetween the first letters every time you can use the following instead of `\cs_new_eq:NN \firstofwords \crosfield_first_of_words:nn`:

```
\newcommand* \firstofwords { \crosfield_first_of_words:nn {.} }
```

---

**Edit2:**

This variant only places the first argument to `\firstofwords` between elements, but not after the last one.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstof}[1]{\expandafter\checkfirst#1\@nil}
\def\checkfirst#1{%
  \ifx\UTFviii@two@octets#1%
  \expandafter\gettwooctets
  \else
  \expandafter\@car\expandafter#1%
  \fi
}
\def\gettwooctets#1#2#3\@nil{\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \crosfield_first_of_words:nn #1#2
  { \exp_not:e { \__crosfield_first_of_words:e { \text_purify:n {#2} } {#1} } }
\group_begin:
\cs_set:Npn \__crosfield_tmp:n #1
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words:n ##1 ##2
      {
        \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:Nnw \use_none:n {##2} ##1 #1 % #1 is a space
          \q_recursion_tail #1 % #1 is a space
          \q_recursion_stop
      }
  }
\__crosfield_tmp:n { ~ }
\group_end:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__crosfield_first_of_words:n { e }
\makeatletter
\cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:Nnw #1 #2 #3 ~
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#3}
    #1 {#2}
    \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:oNTF {#3} \UTFviii@two@octets
      { \__crosfield_first_of_words_aux:nnw #3 \q_stop }
      { \tl_head:n {#3} }
    \__crosfield_first_of_words_spaces:Nnw \exp_not:n {#2}
  }
\makeatother
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF { o }
% there can't be a \q_stop in the argument as that would've caused an infinite
% loop in \text_purify:n, so this is fine and faster than allowing arbitrary
% contents.
\cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_first_of_words_aux:nnw #1#2#3 \q_stop
  { \exp_not:n { #1#2 } }

% define a LaTeX2e name for the above function
\cs_new_eq:NN \firstofwords \crosfield_first_of_words:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

:\firstofwords{.\,}{Vladimir Владимир}.:

\firstofwords{.}{foo bar baz}

\end{document}
```

If you want to always use `.\,` between elements and a `.` after the last one you can use

```
\newcommand\firstofwords[1]{ \crosfield_first_of_words:nn {.\,} {#1} . }
```

Instead of the `\cs_new_eq:NN`-line.

Comment: Thanks for the fine code! But it seems that the first argument to the `\firstofwords` function is not needed. There should always be a dot char and in this sense it does not need to be passed inside the function.

Comment: Thank you **Skillmon**! This is almost exactly what I need. Can you say one more thing pls? Now if I add a dot and a small non-breaking space as an argument to the `\crosfield_first_of_words:nn {.\,}` command, these characters will be added after each initial, but I need the `.\,` to be added only between the initials. Only a dot is needed at the end of the result (like `A.\,F.`). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Crosfield just add an `\unskip` after the last one to remove it: `\firstofwords{.\,}{Some string here}\unskip`. If you don't like to add `\unskip` for this I could create some other code, but that needs time (and I don't have much time today)

Comment: Unfortunately `\unskip` trick doesn't quite work. It's easier to put a negative space `\!` after `\q_recursion_stop`. Although this is of course also just dirty trick.

Comment: @Crosfield oh, sorry my bad, `\,` uses `\kern` in text mode, so can't be `\unskip`ped.

Comment: @Crosfield I've posted an edit of some code variant which will work without such "hacks" as negative spaces.

Comment: oh, thanks! This is the fine solution! For some reason I can't put a nickname @Skillmon in front here

Comment: @Crosfield that's fine, under my answer I'll get notified of every comment, iirc. Either way glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

With `expl3` there is `\text_map_inline:nn` that can do what you want. The idea is to just break the mapping after the first item, adding the desired period.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\firstof}{m}
 {
  \crosfield_firstof:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__crosfield_firstof_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \crosfield_firstof:n
 {
  % split the input at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__crosfield_firstof_items_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  % extract the first item and add a period
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__crosfield_firstof_items_seq \__crosfield_firstof:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__crosfield_firstof:n
 {% map the elements, breaking after the first
  \text_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \text_map_break:n { . } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

\firstof{Vladimir Fedorovich} 

\firstof{Владимир Фёдорович}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Borrowing some code from Skillmon's answer we can get expandability.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\firstof}{m}
 {
  \crosfield_firstof:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \crosfield_firstof:n #1
 {
  \exp_not:e { \__crosfield_firstof:n { #1 } }
 }
\group_begin:
\cs_set:Npn \__crosfield_tmp:n #1
 {
  \cs_new:Nn \__crosfield_firstof:n
   {
    \__crosfield_firstof_item:w ##1 #1 % #1 is a space
    \q_recursion_tail #1 % #1 is a space
    \q_recursion_stop
   }
 }
\__crosfield_tmp:n { ~ }
\group_end:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__crosfield_firstof:n { e }

\cs_new:Npn \__crosfield_firstof_item:w #1 ~
 {
  \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n { #1 }
  \text_map_function:nN { #1 } \__crosfield_firstof_do:n 
  \__crosfield_firstof_item:w
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__crosfield_firstof_do:n { #1 \text_map_break:n { . } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstof{Vladimir}

\firstof{Владимир}

\firstof{Vladimir Fedorovich}

\firstof{Владимир Фёдорович}

\edef\test{\firstof{Владимир Фёдорович}}

\show\test

\end{document}
```

The `\show` command will print

```
> \test=macro:
->В.Ф..
```

on the console, witnessing the full expandability.

Comment: I suspect over the next few days we might end up with something indexed ;)

Comment: @JosephWright I'll have a beer, in the meantime. Maybe a few beers.

Comment: @egreg absolutely pro the beer part, cheers! I was considering using the `\text_map...` internals, but don't ask me why I decided against it... Maybe because of the space-splitting part? :)