Get the first character of a string or macro
I essentially just want a simple command like \firstcharacter{} that returns the first character of it's input. It should work like the following:
\newcommand{\example}{Lorem ipsum}
\firstcharacter{\example} % should return "L"

\firstcharacter{} % should return an empty string/nothing

\firstcharacter{This is a string} % should return "T"
\firstcharacter{\S} should return the section symbol

I've tried numerious solutions here, but nothing seems to work the way I want to. I don't want to rely on external packages like xstring and the solution should work with LaTeX2.

Define "character" . If you just need ascii it is easy if you need to cope with é then it may be harder

This is a string is a token list: a string in TeX is something different. What result do you want for école in pdfTeX?

@JosephWright e acute seems to be the example of the day

@JosephWright I'm sorry, I'm not familair enough with Tex/LaTeX to know the difference.  To answer you question, I would want it to return "é". To generalise, as long as it is a character that can occure in a text (this includes mathematical symbols, greek symbols and symbols like \S as I've mentioned), the command should be able  to return it.

you expanded \example once and got a leading L, but what would you do with \newcommand\example{\textbf{x}yz}  If you just take the leading token you'll get \textbf  without its argument is that intended?

but for pdftex é is not simply a character, it is the two separate bytes of its UTF-8 encoding which when expanded expand to \'{e} which when executed will either add an acute accent over an e or select the pre-composed e-acute character if teh current font encoding has that.

@DavidCarlisle That would be okay. I only intend to use "tokens" (if I use the term correctly), macro's and empty input (\firstcharacter{}). If é makes it terribly complicated I would be willing to work around that, but a greek symbol or something like \S must work

but you expand \example once then the first token is L but if you expand \S once you get \protect\S_ as that is a robust command but you don't want to just take \protect presumably.

I see what you mean and how this complicates stuff. Is there a way to automatically keep expanding until you get something that LaTeX would consider a singular symbol. For example, if it would return, \S or \'{e} etc. and I use that, it would be rendered as a single symbol right? The reason I'm struggeling with this so much seems that I really have no clue how latex converts a token/symbol/string into a symbol that can be displayed

but what would you want from \textbf{abc} xyz  just a or \textbf{a}  or something else?. Basically if you allow arbitrary input the problem is  undefined and/or arbitrarily hard, but if you constrain the input it may be trivial, it all depends on the details....

The way this command will be used is to get the first "character/symbol" from something like \sectionname, \partname etc. This would be language dependent using babel, so it is fair to assume that stuff like é ä or other non-ascii symbols could occur. It is safe to assume that something like \textbf{abc} won't be encountered so you don't need to account for that (other the answer would be that it should return 'a'). The only other option would be that a section symbol would be used or perhaps a other symbol. I hope this is a bit less vague

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690693/1090

Looks like a job for \text_map_function:nN:
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \firstchar { m }
  {
    \text_map_function:nN {#1} \__firstchar:n
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__firstchar:n #1
  {
    \exp_not:n {#1}
    \text_map_break:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\firstchar{école}
\newcommand\saved{\S tuff}
\firstchar{\saved}

\end{document}


I get the error Missing \endcsname inserted.


@Texnicallyausername with exactly this code? or when you incorporate it into some larger document?

It was an issue on my end, now it works great! The answer given my @DavidCarlisle seems nice too, but this solution appears simpler.

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It works with LaTeX2e, and it doesn't rely on external packages, as (I think) the OP has required.
The macro \firstchar depends on the assumption that its argument is either a string or evaluates to a string. An empty string is ok, and the string may contain non-ASCII utf8-encoded characters such as é and μ, as long as they are single code-point graphemes. (As @JosephWright has pointed out in a comment, characters with multi-codepoint graphemes, such as the character n̈ is Spın̈al Tap, will not be picked up fully. E.g., if n̈ is the first character in the argument of \firstchar, it'll get rendered as n, not n̈. I trust this won't be much of an issue in practice.) In contrast, \firstchar will not work properly on arguments such as \S and \textbf{a}.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\firstchar}[1]{%
    \directlua{tex.sprint(unicode.utf8.sub('#1',1,1))}}
  
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\example}{Lorem ipsum}
\firstchar{\example}         % return 'L'

\firstchar{}.                % return empty string, followed by '.'

\firstchar{This is a string} % return 'T'

\firstchar{Γεια σου Κόσμο}   % return 'Γ'

\firstchar{école}            % return 'é'

%%%\firstchar{\S}            % doesn't work
\end{document}


I know the spec is vague, and you know this, but this won't handle multi-codepoint graphemes as it stands (the classic for me is n̈ is Spın̈al Tap)

@JosephWright - Thanks for this observation. I've edited the paragraph in question to incorporate this point.

If you are using a modern TeX engine with Unicode support (i.e. luaTeX, XeTeX) then you can implement your task very simply by TeX primitives and elementary TeX macro programming:
\def\firstcharacter#1{\expandafter\firstcharacterA#1{}\end}
\def\firstcharacterA#1#2\end{#1}

\firstcharacter{école}   % returns é

\def\example{Lorem ipsum}
\firstcharacter{\example} % returns L

\firstcharacter{This is a string} % returns T

\firstcharacter{\S} % returns section symbol

\firstcharacter{} % returns nothing

\bye

If you are using an old (and obsolete) TeX engine without Unicode support (i.e. pdfTeX without encTeX initialized) then the first example crashes because this engine tokenizes its input byte by byte, no character by character. And the é character is implemented in UTF8 encoded files (common encoding of files for Unicode) by more bytes. Then you have to create more tricky macro. But because such an engine is obsolete, I don't present the macro here.
The example with \S may crash in pdfTeX too because it may be an old plain TeX macro and not the equivalent to the single Unicode character §.
Note that pdfTeX with csplain format works, because it initializes encTeX. But both these tools are old and obsolete too.
